# How should we go about receiving faxes with a server?

Tags: ubuntu-server, windows-server, fax

What kind of software is there for receiving faxes from a computer? I want to be able to run it on a server so it's always receiving. Something that flexible with how it stores the faxes, and how it sends notifications would be good. I'd also like a good API or some way of adding custom functionality to it for notifications and such.

It will most likely be a Windows server but Linux isn't totally out.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have quite good experience with [hylafax](http://hylafax.org) server. Runs on *NIXes.

Comment: I don't know if we'll go for this or not, but it looks pretty good. I was hoping to find some good Windows solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple and relatively cheap, Windows XP already contains FAX send/receive software as part of the release.  Seems to work fine for my purposes and I can print to the FAX using their FAX printer driver from any windows application.

Comment: I need something more "enterprisy".